# Outputting data using system.out from array that's inside a loop JAVA

Tags: java

The code below supposed to take users input:

- name
- bad/good teeth

Program should allow the user to enter that in an array and loop 10 times and then output that list in a table format ( the format you can find at the bottom of the code)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pbclass;
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        pbclass objectt = new pbclass();
        objectt.dentistpractice();
    }

    public void dentistpractice()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] patientFamName = new String[10];
        String[] patientFirstName = new String[10];
        String[] PatientGoodTeeth = new String[10];
        String[] PatientBadTeeth = new String[10];

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter surname name ");
            patientFamName[i] = scan.nextLine();
            if (patientFamName[i].equalsIgnoreCase("close") ==true)
            {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Enter first name ");
            patientFirstName[i] = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter good teeth ");
            PatientGoodTeeth[i] = scan.nextLine();
            int numconverterForHomeTeam = Integer.parseInt(PatientGoodTeeth[i]);
            System.out.println("Enter score for away team: ");
            PatientBadTeeth[i] = scan.nextLine();
            int numconverterForAwayTeam = Integer.parseInt(PatientBadTeeth[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(patientFamName[0] + patientFirstName[0] + " ||||||| " +PatientGoodTeeth[0]  + PatientBadTeeth[0] );
    System.out.println(patientFamName[1] + patientFirstName[1] + " ||||||| " +PatientGoodTeeth[1]  + PatientBadTeeth[1] );

}
```

The problem I am facing is that I do not know how to output the data in a simple way. What if the array was 1000 variables or even longer?

Additionally, how do I prevent 'null' from showing on the display table. If the user types 'exit' the loop should stop and display the already inputted data excluding null values.

Comment: You're using what's called *parallel arrays*, and it's an antipattern. The better way to do things is to define a `class Patient` that has all the attributes for one patient, and then to add new copies of `Patient` to a list (instead of an array), which sizes automatically.

Comment: Why is all the text in **bold**? Also, please format the code correctly, and make sure it is compilable.

Comment: If you are concerning about '**NullPointerException** use exception when you are displaying output and you can print already added data in another loop as it is shown in answer below' so that you might be able to handle an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want. But you can improve the print outcome part.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class pbclass {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            pbclass objectt = new pbclass();
            objectt.dentistpractice();
        }

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         int array_length=10;
         int array_length2=0;
        String[] patientFamName = new String[array_length];
        String[] patientFirstName = new String[array_length];
        Integer[] PatientGoodTeeth = new Integer[array_length];
        Integer[] PatientBadTeeth = new Integer[array_length];



        public void dentistpractice() {


            for (int i = 0; i < array_length; ++i) {
                System.out.println("Enter surname name ");
                patientFamName[i] = scan.nextLine();
                if (patientFamName[i].equalsIgnoreCase("close")) {
                    break;
                }
                array_length2++;
                System.out.println("Enter first name ");
                patientFirstName[i] = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter good teeth ");
                PatientGoodTeeth[i] = scan.nextInt();
                scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter score for away team: ");
                PatientBadTeeth[i] = scan.nextInt();
                scan.nextLine();
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < array_length2; ++i){
                System.out.println("-----------------------");
                System.out.println(" | " +patientFamName[i] + " | "+ patientFirstName[i] + " | " + PatientGoodTeeth[i] + " | "+ PatientBadTeeth[i]+ " | ");
            }
            System.out.println("-----------------------");

        }
    }
```